# Quicker to access menu bar with keyboard: PC or Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop

[Some background info:] I used to use Photoshop with PC and pressing `alt > i > p` (or `c`? cannot verify this now as I am using a Mac) quickly crops a selected area of the image. However, I am now working with a Mac and I have to either press [ctrl + fn + f2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1322/can-i-open-the-menu-with-keyboard) `> i > down arrow > c > r` to crop, or [set a keyboard shortcut for cropping](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7011/photoshop-select-item-and-crop-it-directly).

I have been a long term PC user. I like using Mac, especially the [relative-pathed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) shortcut-like [Aliases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(Mac_OS)). But in PC, after pressing `alt` and [moving keyboard focus to the menu bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_key#Alt_key_pressed_alone), the interface would underline the key for quick keyboard access.

It makes me wonder, ***is it just faster for PC to access the menu bar, or there is an other way on Mac that is quicker than that?***